# Yo generator stuck to generate application for a long time

Tags: meanjs, yo

When I am going to create an application in meanjs using yo meanjs it's stuck to for a long time.

```
D:\WorkShop\MEAN>yo meanjs
You're using the official MEAN.JS generator.
? What mean.js version would you like to generate? 0.4.0
0.4.0
? In which folder would you like the project to be generated? This can be changed later. mongoapp
Cloning the MEAN repo.......
? What would you like to call your application? mongoapp
? How would you describe your application? Full-Stack JavaScript with MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, and Node.js
? How would you describe your application in comma seperated key words? MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, Node.js
? What is your company/author name? deep
? Would you like to generate the article example CRUD module? Yes
? Would you like to generate the chat example module? No
Running npm install for you....
This may take a couple minutes.
```

And then the following error is coming

```
Error: Command failed: cd mongoapp && npm install
.
.
.
.
etc
```

But I have installed nodejs

Comment: It's worth noting that MEAN.JS is no longer maintained (http://meanjs.org/generator.html).  Anyone know of a Yo generator for MEAN that is maintained?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the yo generator had difficulties creating the `mongoapp` directory that's why the `cd mongoapp` command failed, OR you don't have `nmp` installed and the `npm install` command failed.